# How to compare CSV files column wise?

Tags: c#, csv, compare

I have two CSV files who are expected to have the same content. However, the second CSV file has the same data but the columns are rearranged in it. I am more concerned about comparing the data though. Is there any way I can compare the two CSV files on the basis of columns? I mean, comparing column 1 from firstCSV with column 2 of secondCSV. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: convert and or load the csv file into a datatable and then you can do the comparison based on the `DataTable.Rows[0]["ColumnName]` value

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that rows are in the same order, you could get the value and column name from one CSV file and compare it with the same column in the next CSV file, something like so:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> csv1 = ...
List<Dictionary<string, string>> csv2 = ...

for(int i = 0; i < Math.Min(csv1.Count(), csv2.Count()); i++)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> csv2Line = csv2[i];
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in csv1[i])
    {
        string columnName = kvp.Key;
        if(csv2Line[columnName] != kvp.Value)
            //Do something when the comparison fails.
    }
}
```